# Can't pip install mysqlclient or cython or lxml on windows 10

Tags: python, mysql, visual-c++, windows-10, cython

I can't pip install mysqlclient on windows 10 without getting the following error even though I have Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools installed.

```
>pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.9.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\steve\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_yigsmi6\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn27ys7vspip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64- 3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\steve\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_yigsmi6\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-gsvbkpt7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\steve\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\steve\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_yigsmi6\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-gsvbkpt7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_yigsmi6\mysqlclient\
```

I have Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools installed but I still get this error. It will do this if I try to install lxml and cython as well. I don't know what else to do because I have Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools installed as the error specifies. I installed Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools from [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).

What do I need to do to successfully pip install mysqlclient or cython or lxml with pip3 on windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way should be to use Python binary wheels. You can find a great collection of those "unofficial" binaries  at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs. I actually use them for the packages which fail to install when trying to install them from PyPi.

- [mysqlclient wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)
- [lxml wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)